# Word choice: "accept", "sign", something else?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

I had sent an express mail to my friend several days ago, which contained some documents. After checking online, I can see the express mail has been delivered. Now I'd like to write an email to my friend to ask her about it.

When referring to the delivery, should I ask her if she "accepted the documents", "signed the documents", or something else?

In Chinese, we usually say something like "Have you signed and accepted the express mail?" But I'm not sure what the proper way is to say it in English.

Comment: Possibly you mean "she signed ***for*** the documents", meaning that she signed some paper saying that she had received the documents.

Comment: +1 for responsiveness to the comments. Peter Shor has put his finger on the correct idiom. You know *somebody* signed for the documents, so I would say "I see the documents have been delivered and signed for; did you actually receive them?" That covers the possibility that somebody else took delivery and did not pass the documents on to your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to ask somebody whether they got your express mail is probably just:

> Have you received the documents?

To ask whether she signed the form that the delivery company presented, that says that she received the documents, you would say:

> Did you sign for the documents?

(Not "did you sign the documents" ... that is asking whether you put your signature on the documents themselves.)